# How can I reference angularjs template files within a visualforce page?

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am creating a Visualforce plugin that allows me to add data to the Account and Opportunity pages. The data I am adding easily follows the model of a SPA, so I decided to use AngularJS within my Visualforce plugin.

So far, everything worked fine when I was only using the Account page -- I was able to just add text/ng-template scripts to render my particular views in the application, and edit just one file.

Now, I am extending the plugin to work on the Opportunity Page, too; the front-facing portion of plugin literally requires the **exact** same code to render on both the opportunity and account page.

I attempted first to find some way to render a partial view in Apex so that I could just have all my display logic in one file; it wasn't ideal, and there didn't seem to be a way to do that.

Then, I tried using linking to StaticResource html files that contain my angular page templates, but for some reason (despite getting a url for them), I cannot link to them; I think Salesforce simply does not let me link to static resources in this manner.

How exactly can I use template files in order to not have to copy/paste all my code, once in a visualforce page for the AccountController, and once in my visualforce page for the OpportunityController?

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a post [reference AngularJS templates within VisualForce](http://digitalflask.com/blog/reference-angularjs-templates-within-visualforce/).

I've mention three ways to do so:

**1. Use templates as an individual VisualForce Page (VFP).**

Then you can reference then as `templateUrl: "/apex/MyDirective",`. This method allows you to use `apex` tags inside your templates, but rendering might be slow.

**2. Use templates as VisualForce components.**

Create an `apex:component` with `<script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective">...</script>` code inside. Then, add your component to the `apex:page`, e.g. `<c:Template />`. Now you can reference it by id: `templateUrl: "myDirective",`.

**3. Use templates as static resources.**

Create a static resource, which will contain your HTML templates, e.g. `Templates`. Now you have two options: either use `<base>` element or global javascript variable.

1) Define base as: `<base href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Templates, '')}" />` and reference your template files: `template: '/myDirective.html',`

2) Create global variable:

```
<script>
  window.RESOURCE_ROOT = "{!URLFOR($Resource.Templates, '')}";
</script>
```

and use it as: `templateUrl: RESOURCE_ROOT + '/MyDirective.html'`

I'm using the Static Resource approach, but notice that you won't be able to use `apex` tags inside these templates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you tried to implement a partial but I would suggest to use [apex:include](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm) tag to include a visualforce page with the content that you want to replicate.

Other option would be to create an [apex:component](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_component.htm) that contain the templates and can receive parameters to load selective content for example.